# CSS 3 Transform scale crashes FullCalendar

Tags: css, fullcalendar

I am working on a project which needs to be scaled with CSS3 Transfom scale. All pages done well but the page which contains Fullcalendar. When I use transform css on that page Full calendar component do not scale itself properly. All events and drop boxes rendered wrong.

Any Help?

Comment: You need to include your code for people to help!

Answer (score 0):

What elements are you applying the transform to? Try applying the transform to the page's body element and see if that works.